How to fix "Type '{}' cannot be used as an index type" error
interface TicketTime {
    startTime: string;
    endTime: string;
}

 interface TicketInfo {
    id: number;
    from: string;
    to: string;
    company: string;
    price: number;
    time: TicketTime;


    duration: number;
    connectionAmount: number | null;
}
 type info = TicketInfo [];
 let flightsData: info  [
   {
    
   }, ]

Playground
I don't understand why this error appears and how to fix it.

...what exactly were you expecting that to do? Are you trying to assign a value to flightsData?

I think you're just missing the equals sign. let flightsData: info = [ {} ]

Im trying to make mock data for searching tickets

As someone commented you simply needed to add a = to your flightsData object.
Also here is what you want it to look like.
interface TicketTime {
    startTime: string;
    endTime: string;
}

 interface TicketInfo {
    id: number;
    from: string;
    to: string;
    company: string;
    price: number;
    time: TicketTime;
    duration: number;
    connectionAmount: number | null;
}
 type info = TicketInfo [];
 let flightsData: info = [{
   id: 0,
   from: "",
   to: "",
   company: "",
   price: 0,
   time: {startTime: "startTime", endTime: "endTime"},
   duration: 0,
   connectionAmount: null
}]


Thanks! That worked. I feel so dumb rn)

Haha, happens to the best of us, as long as you learn from it you'll be fine don't worry :)

@Melman if this solved your problem, mark as complete.

TL;DR: you are missing a = sign after let flightsData: info.
In typescript you may define types inline, so when you write something like this:
let label: string = 'something';

You declared a variable, defined its type as string and assigned a string value;
You can also declare something more complex, like an Array of strings:
let labels: string[] = ['something', 'something else'];

In your script the word info is defined as a type that is an Array of TicketInfo, so you may use this type like this:
let flightsData: info = [];

If you omit the = symbol you are defining another type: an Array of info, that is an Array of Arrays of TicketInfo:
let flightsData: info[];

In some cases you may add something inside square brackets, and Typescript knows how to use those informations, look at the following example:
type info = TicketInfo ['id'];

In this case we are not declaring an Array of TicketInfo, we are using the property id of TicketInfo, and since id in TicketInfo is a number, now type info is a number too.
And finally, here comes your case. Omitting the = symbol made your script similar to that last example, but since {} cannot be used as key (as id in TicketInfo['id']), you have that error.
let flightsData: info  [
   {
    
   }, ]

This is looking for index {} in an Object, and {} can never be a valid index.
